# TinyMCE 4.x with Angular 1.5.x with ng-repeat getContent of Edited TinyMce Editors

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, tinymce-4, angular-ui-tinymce

Iam creating **TinyMce-Editors** through `ng-repeat`.
The Official Doc to Angular is not really Helpfull
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angularjs/
So Iam asking here for Help :)
After a User did some Edits he shall be able to save this Edits or all Edited Fields in a Database.
Creating the TinyMces in my
**HTML**

```
    <tbody>
            <tr dir-paginate="v in visibleItems = ($ctrl.myCollection| filter:{Name:searchK,value1:searchV}| filterByProd:selectedProduct) |orderBy: sortType:sortReverse|itemsPerPage:10 as results">
             <td>
              <div ui-tinymce='tinymceOptions' ng-model='v.value2'></div>
<!-- in v.value2 is some Text from Databse which I set in the created Editors -->             
</td>
</tbody>
```

**controller.js**

```
    'use strict';

    (function(){

    class HelpComponent {
      constructor($http, $scope) {
          this.$http = $http;
          this.$scope = $scope;
          this.$scope.tinymceOptions ={
            selector: 'div',
            plugins: 'save code',
            save_enablewhendirty: true,
            save_onsavecallback: () => {console.log('Save');},
            toolbar1:' undo redo | bold underline italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright',
            toolbar2: 'save | code'
          };
        }//closing constructor
 getContent(){
   angular.forEach(this.myCollection, value =>{
     console.log(value);//iteratin my collection  //how to iterate all Editors?
   })
   }
    ... some more code
    }//closing class

    angular.module('App')
      .component('help', {
        templateUrl: 'help.html',
        controller: HelpComponent,
      });
    })();
```

1. Question:
   The Plugin of Tiny `save` shows me the Save Button and is only active after some Edits. But Clicking on the Button is not doing anything but shall call

   save_onsavecallback: () => {console.log('Save');}//no console log output,
2. Question:
   How can I Iterate through all Editors and get only the Edited ones?
   In the docs is the

   tinyMCE.activeEditor.isDirty()

Function.
What means tinyMCE? -> have I just to write or does it stands for something?
activeEditor ? -> I want to Iterate so there I have to place a Variable?

Comment: How did you add tinyMCE ? but angular-ui-tinymce or via script ? Did you create unique ng-model for each tinyMCE ? please post a JSFiddle link

Comment: I did add it through `angular-ui-tinymce`. `ng-model` is not unique I think because its Dynamically generated with `ng-repeat`

Comment: JSFiddle please